# Can't update Text Edit Text QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having an issue. My `textEditBox` doesn't seem to be updating when my `Addtext` function is called.

Here's my `Addtext`:

```
void CTextBox::AddText(QString string, QString spriteString)  
{

    textBrowser->setText(string + spriteString);
    update();

}
```

Another class then calls the function and it should add text to the `textbox` but it doesn't.

Comment: What is textBrowser? I suppose it is a QTextEdit*. How do you create it; Through QDesigner or with code?

Comment: With code, I orginally was going to make a QTestBrowser but changed it and forgot to change the variable name.

Comment: I think there's more code you need to show to figure out the problem. The `update` should not be necessary--changing the text will cause the `QTextEdit` to be repainted. Are you sure the function is actually getting called? (Use qDebug() and make sure.)

Comment: It's definately being called, with the debugger, it clearly goes in the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you call CTextBox::AddText()? `update()` only schedules a `paintEvent()` for later, when the program returns to the event loop. That means that

1. you actually need to have an event loop, ie. at some point you need to call `qApp->exec()`;
2. you need to allow the programm some time to `qApp->processEvents()` (insert that after `update()`), if you want any paining done within a blocking `while() {...}` or something like that.

Edit: Come to think of it, you shouldn't even need to call `update()` nor `processEvents()` if your program returns to the event loop some time after `AddText`, so there really seems to be an issue with the event loop. Post your main.cpp, will you?

Comment: I call it everytime new text needs to be added e.g.

Comment: addtext(created node, nodename). I tried to replace printf with my own method.

Comment: Which basically I want to do the same thing.

Comment: Edited my answer. Check your main.cpp, please. Do you have an executed `QApplication` running? It's not enough to just create it and then open a window and expect anything to happen. (Don't know if that's what your doing, but it seems like it.)

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 QApplication a(argc, argv);
 FileLoaderQT w;
 w.show();
 return a.exec();
}

Comment: Is there a better way of posting it?

Comment: I'm afraid not (not in a comment anyway), but that's fine. Ok, next idea! :) You basically call `QTextEdit::setText()`, right? That overwrites all previous input: maybe the last thing you "add" is an empty line? Try `append()` instead and tell us what happens.

Comment: No luck. the first part of the string is constant so I don't think there should be a blank line. I was wondering if that my text edit box is in a seperate glass to the rest of the GUI, the way I got it to draw was with the setCentralWidget(textedit), do I have to update that everytime I add text to my textbox?

Comment: Can you just try calling `textBrowser->append("Test String");` below the construction of your QTextEdit and let us know if you see anything written in it?

Comment: I cannot say what is going wrong if you do not provide some more code.

Comment: I think I've worked it out. Basically I've made two text boxes one of which is basically not being used. So I'm going to make it a singleton and try again.

Comment: Making a text box singleton? Why??? Singleton is a design pattern which means that you can create an object at most one time. The application could be a singleton, a logging class could be a singleton but the QTextBox **must not** be a singleton

Comment: It worked, I surely don't want to be able to make more than one class of CTextBox? I'm not using QTextBox I'm using QtextEdit and I'm making the class that I made the QTestEdit in a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a trivial example of what it sounds like you are trying to do. Maybe you can see where your design differs?

Notice: no explicit `update()` is needed. I think that's a red herring. I think it far more likely that (1) you are somehow calling your `AddText` method with empty strings, or (2) your *real* text edit is a different variable, and have somehow created two of them and are updating one that just exists in memory and was never added to a layout. Perhaps the code of your FileLoaderQT would help? (You can edit your question rather than posting in comments.)

```
#include <QtGui>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QMainWindow w;
  QTextEdit *edit = new QTextEdit;
  w.setCentralWidget(edit);
  edit->setText("Hello world!");
  w.show();
  edit->append("Hello world again!");
  return app.exec();
}
```